# Environment property wrapper throws +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, property-wrapper

Why is the entityForName on `Environment(\.managedObjectContext).wrappedValue` always nil?
I get this error `+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Project'`

With `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext` I don't get this error.
But I need to initialize the view with my controller that needs `NSManagedObjectContext` to be passed.

Can someone help to understand why these two lines don't return the same object? Or is it the same?

```
@main
struct umbrellaApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext // Works
    @StateObject private var controller: ContentViewController
    
    init() {
        // Crashes
        let viewContextValue = Environment(\.managedObjectContext).wrappedValue

        let controller = ContentViewController(managedObjectContext: viewContextValue)
        self._controller = StateObject(wrappedValue: controller)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

The initializer of `ContentViewController`.

```
init(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    self.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
    self.projectsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: Project.projectsFetchRequest,
      managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext,
      sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        
    super.init()

    projectsController.delegate = self
    do {
        try projectsController.performFetch()
        self.projects = projectsController.fetchedObjects ?? []
    } catch {
        print("failed to fetch projects!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, `Environment` needs the `@`, it is a wrapper. What you are trying to do isn't a documented use of `Environment`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environment

Long answer,

You haven't provided a Minimal Reproducible product but here is what I see

```
    let viewContextValue = Environment(\.managedObjectContext).wrappedValue
```

It doesn't work because as you know the `@Environment` isn't available at this point or you would just use `viewContext`.

```
    let controller = ContentViewController(managedObjectContext: viewContextValue)
```

I see what you are trying to do here but as stated above `@Environment` just isn't available during `init`

```
    self._controller = StateObject(wrappedValue: controller)
```

And this while it "works" on the surface it kind of defeats the virtues of `StateObject`

> SwiftUI might create or recreate a view at any time, so it’s important
> that initializing a view with a given set of inputs always results in
> the same view. As a result, it’s unsafe to create an observed object
> inside a view. Instead, SwiftUI provides the StateObject attribute for
> this purpose. You can safely create a Book instance inside a view this
> way:
> `@StateObject var book = Book()`
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

In my experience custom `init`s in SwiftUI don't provide a reliable experience. I try to stay away from them as much as I can. If you have to do custom work upon `init` do it in a `class` as a `ViewModel`/`ViewController` that is also an `ObservableObject` a `View` shouldn't do any work.

If you want an alternative to what you want to do this see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346375/swift-nil-error-when-using-self-moc-save-to-save-in-core-data/67348842#67348842)

All you need is

```
let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
```

Inside your `ContentViewController` and initialize your `StateObject` like this.

```
@StateObject private var controller: ContentViewController = ContentViewController()
```

Here is a sample where I used a `FetchedResultsController` it has sections

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
class TaskListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.previewAware()
    @Published var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Task>?
    
    init() {
        setupController()
    }
    func setupController() {
        do{
            fetchedResultsController = try retrieveFetchedController(sortDescriptors: nil, predicate: nil, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Task.isComplete))
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    func deleteObject(object: Task) {
        persistenceController.container.viewContext.delete(object)
        save()
    }
    func save() {
        do {
            if persistenceController.container.viewContext.hasChanges{
                try persistenceController.container.viewContext.save()
                objectWillChange.send()
            }else{
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
//MARK: FetchedResultsController setup
extension TaskListViewModel{
    func retrieveFetchedController(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, sectionNameKeyPath: String) throws -> NSFetchedResultsController<Task> {
        
        return try initFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath)
    }
    private func initFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, sectionNameKeyPath: String) throws -> NSFetchedResultsController<Task> {
        fetchedResultsController = getFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath)
        //fetchedResultsController!.delegate = self
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
            return fetchedResultsController!
            
        } catch {
            print( error)
            throw error
        }
    }
    func getFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, sectionNameKeyPath: String) -> NSFetchedResultsController<Task> {
        
        return NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: getEntityFetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate), managedObjectContext: persistenceController.container.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath, cacheName: nil)
    }
    private func getEntityFetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?) -> NSFetchRequest<Task>
    {
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        if sortDescriptors != nil{
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        }else{
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Task.dateAdded), ascending: false)]
        }
        if predicate != nil{
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        }
        return fetchRequest
    }
}
struct TaskListView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: TaskListViewModel = TaskListViewModel()
    @State var taskToEdit: Task?
    var body: some View {
        
        if vm.fetchedResultsController?.sections != nil{
            List{
                ForEach(0..<vm.fetchedResultsController!.sections!.count){idx in
                    let section = vm.fetchedResultsController!.sections![idx]
                    TaskListSectionView(objects: section.objects as? [Task] ?? [], taskToEdit: $taskToEdit, sectionName: section.name).environmentObject(vm)
                    
                }
            }.sheet(item: $taskToEdit, onDismiss: {
                vm.save()
            }){editingTask in
                TaskEditView(task: editingTask)
            }
            
        }else{
            Image(systemName: "empty")
        }
    }
}

struct TaskEditView: View {
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $task.name.bound)
    }
}
struct TaskListSectionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: TaskListViewModel
    let objects: [Task]
    @State var deleteAlert: Alert = Alert(title: Text("test"))
    @State var presentAlert: Bool = false
    @Binding var taskToEdit: Task?
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = true
    var sectionName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text(sectionName) ,                content: {
            ForEach(objects, id: \.self){obj in
            let task = obj as Task
            Button(action: {
                taskToEdit = task
            }, label: {
                Text(task.name ?? "no name")
            })
            .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            
            
        }.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        })
        
    }
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            deleteAlert = Alert(title: Text("Sure you want to delete?"), primaryButton: Alert.Button.destructive(Text("yes"), action: {
                let objs = offsets.map { objects[$0] }
                
                for obj in objs{
                    
                    vm.deleteObject(object: obj)
                }
                //Because the objects in the sections aren't being directly observed
                vm.objectWillChange.send()
                
            }), secondaryButton: Alert.Button.cancel())
            
            
            self.presentAlert = true
            
        }
    }
}

struct TaskListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            TaskListView()
        
    }
}
```

`previewAware()` is just a method that decides wether to pass the built-in `preview` or `shared`

```
static func previewAware() -> PersistenceController{
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"] == "1" {
        return PersistenceController.preview
    }else{
        return PersistenceController.shared
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to pass a view context within the `PreviewProvider` to my view to preview inside Xcode.
I see you do have `previewAware()` on your `PersistanceController`. Would that solve my problem?

Comment: That is a convince method that I made. The `PersistenceController` automatically provides the `preview` controller that the standard code makes if it detects that you are running in Previews. The code is above just add that `func` in the `PersistenceController`

Comment: That solves my problem. With this func, I don't need to pass the `managedObjectContext` in `Environment` in previews and and code. I just call `PersistanceController.previewAware()` in my controller and there's my viewContext.
Thank you!

Comment: Yup, you can use `previewAware()` in your `View` too. That way you don't have to worry about changing it at all. In my `PersistenceController` I have `shared` as `private` that way I don't call it accidentally.