# Passing Core Data Context to SwiftUI view from a UIkit VC

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

a beginner IOS developer here. So my current project uses UIKit + SwiftUI
so I want to pass the CoreData context to a swiftUI view from a VC. are there any method do pass it? Thanks

ps : I tried to do something from raywenderlich tutorials

```
let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
let contentView = MovieList().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

tried to duplicate it, but well I cant do that in a VC, it gave me error

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var container: NSPersistentContainer!
    let context  = container.viewContext
    let childView:UIHostingController = {
        return UIHostingController(rootView: HomeView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context))
    }()
..................

}
```

well , because you cant ( I think)

Comment: This looks all wrong, you should have a separate class (singleton or shared) that holds your NSPersistentContainer instance and that you can call from both places to access the NSManagedObjectContect. If you are on a newer version for Xcode then creating a new project that uses Core Data will generate such a class for you so try that.

Comment: thank you, are there any reference i could use? thanks

Comment: See my edited comment above

Comment: i'm actually creating the project using the latest version of Xcode and it's in the Scenedelegates and AppDelegate

Comment: So then you have a struct PersistenceController already? Why not access the managed object context directly in the SwiftUI view as `PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext`?

Comment: ohh no, it's in the SceneDelegates and AppDelegates

Comment: if not using delegates = new, then no. i am not using the latest template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346375/swift-nil-error-when-using-self-moc-save-to-save-in-core-data/67348842#67348842

Comment: Thank you but the solution you're offering is when the main view is a swiftUI View, but mine is not a swiftUI view